# How to set a cut-off for my damped_sine fit using curve_fit?

Tags: python, plot, curve-fitting

I am fitting a damped sine curve to my plot and I do not want it to take into account values after a certain range because those values result from noise.
I still want to make the plot in the region where noise is present and that is why it is not obvious how I can prevent the fit from taking those points. Otherwise, I could have just restricted my plot in the region without the noise and then make a fit and that would have done it.

Here is my program:

(Note: `x0` and `y0` are defined in a previous cell)

```
x0=np.array(x0)
y0=np.array(y0)

def damped_sine(t, A, lbda, omega):
    r"""y(t) = A \cdot \exp(-\lambda t) \cdot \left( \sin \left( \omega t + \phi ) \right)"""
    return A * np.exp(-lbda * t) * np.cos(omega * t)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(damped_sine,x0,y0)
print(*[f"{val:.2f}+/-{err:.2f}" for val, err in zip(popt, np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)))])
plt.plot(x0,y0)
plt.plot(x0,damped_sine(x0,*popt),'-r')

OUTPUT:
```

[image]

I want the fitted curve to take into account only points till x-axis value =20 as the small oscillations after that seem to come from the noise.

Comment: You have to supply shortened versions of `x0` and `y0` to `curve_fit`. For example, you can create a mask like: `mask = x0[x0 < 20]`, then `x0_fit = x0[mask]` and `y0_fit = y0[mask]`. When you plot it later, you provide `popt` obtained with the shortened arrays, but the longer `x0`. This effectively extrapolates your fit to the other regions. Alternatively, you can use the same mask to create another array and set every point after `x==20` to 0. Sometimes this can be beneficial to the algorithm.